# Is there free wiki source code that will run on the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, open-source, wiki

I found the sample code [cccwiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/cccwiki) which is good, but I would like a wiki that keeps tracks of all revisions to the pages and lets users show diffs and revert to previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed me to [pickywiki](http://bitbucket.org/ianb/pickywiki/). I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/downloads/detail?name=cccwiki_20080409.tar.gz&can=2&q= which is exactly "A simple Google App Engine wiki application" for you to download, try, and modify as you want. You can also browse its sources online at http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/cccwiki/ .

Comment: Thanks, but as my question states I already found that one (the only one I found) and it does not implement revisions.